# mysql restore from data directory

Tags: mysql, restore

I recently asked a question regarding the restoration of a pretty huge (around 300 to 400 GB) mysql database and got some nice suggestions as seen [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68966/mysql-database-restore-takes-long-time). Now, I have backed up the data directory of mysql as well.

So, for example before reinstalling the machine the data directory is present under `/mounts/mysql`.

I have backed up that particular folder and I was wondering if I just restore `/mounts/mysql` folder back in the new machine, will it be ok? Or will there be some problem because the database is not restored using the proper `mysql` command?

Comment: How exactly did you backup /mounts/mysql?

Comment: I used the `rsync` command to dump everything available under `/mounts/mysql`.

Comment: If mysql was running while you're copying the directory, then it's most probably corrupt.

Answer (score 2):

I just use this backup THE WHOLE MYSQL FILES way to migrate a MySQL database, and it worked!

here is my steps

> 1, install MySQL server on the 2nd server with exactly same
>   configuration like 1st server;
>
> 2, stop 1st and 2nd mysqld server
>
> 3, change the 2nd mysql data folder name, which you can find in mysql 
>   configuration file (my.cnf):

```
[root@ntest1 mysql]# cat /etc/my.cnf|grep dir
#dir
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
innodb_data_home_dir=/usr/local/mysql/data
innodb_log_group_home_dir=/usr/local/mysql/data
target_dir=/data/backups/
```

so I change the data/ name to data_bak/

```
mv data data_bak
```

because my innodb data(ibdata1 ...), innodb log(ib_logfile0...), binlgo(mysql-bin.000001...) and other database files (mysql/, yourdatabase/, ...) are all in /user/local/mysql/data/, so I just need copy all this files and folders to the object server with the same location

```
scp -r 10.88.48.111:/usr/local/mysql/data/* /usr/local/mysql/data/
```

note that I use root to copy, so I need to change the roles

```
chown -R mysql.mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
```

and then MySQLd could start up in the next moment